# How to divide all numbers in a list to a number?

Tags: python, list

I have a list contains around 200 numbers. I need a list fraction of them. I mean I have `a=[111,23,25,12,61]`
I want `b=[1/111,1/23,1/25,1/12,1/61]`
How can i do that?

Comment: Fraction or decimal. Fraction will be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a list comprehension:

```
[1.0/x for x in a]
```

Comment: I did but website said I need rep to do that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` to apply a function to every element of a list:

```py
n = [111, 23, 25, 12, 61]
n_fractions = map(lambda x: 1/x, n)
# [0.009009009009009009, 0.043478260869565216, 0.04, 0.08333333333333333, 0.01639344262295082]
```

You can also use the built-in `fractions.Fraction` class to properly express the values as fractions:

```py
n_fractions = list(map(lambda x: Fraction(1, x), n))
# [Fraction(1, 111), Fraction(1, 23), Fraction(1, 25), Fraction(1, 12), Fraction(1, 61)]
```